# How to return all unique number combinations with the sum of N

Tags: python

I've edited my question as I don't think I've explained it well.  The subset_sum function that is linked as a duplicate seems to be when the list of numbers is random but would also work in my situation.  However, it seems to be inefficient for large numbers like my function below.  My questions is for a list of number that is always known based on the value of N.

If N is 10 the list of numbers would be 1 through 9 or range(1, N).  The function should return all unique number combinations from 1 to 9 with a sum of 10.  In this case my function below will solve this and return 9 however for large numbers it takes a very long time.  It seems to me there should be a better way to solve this when the range of numbers is known than having to iterate through each possible combination.  Maybe I'm wrong though.

```
import itertools

def counter(n):
    count = 0
    l = range(1, n)
    for i in range(1, n):
        for c in itertools.combinations(l, i):
            if sum(c) == n:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: 5+3+2 is also possible, so it'll return 9.

Comment: Ah thanks!  I thought the function was working properly but couldn't think of the last possibility when I was typing up the question.  My question then is really around how this can be made to calculate the solution more efficiently without having to iterate through each possible combination.

Comment: That's a [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and, although ordered in your case, it still is an NP-complete problem so you cannot solve it by a simple formula. A fellow SO member went to the trouble of writing out the code for solving it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633515

Comment: Compute a few, let's say for n in range(10, 20), then throw your sequence into oeis.org

Comment: @zwer Doesn't look like subset sum at all.

Comment: The question marked as the duplicate does discuss your point about efficiency, see the part about this problem being NP Hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you search for is partition function p. 
Check out https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)
It contains recursive formula which is only linear in terms of input.